# Jquery validation to textbox on paste command

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML textbox, I restrict from special characters being entered. But when I paste using Ctrl + V the validation doesn't fire.

Comment: Show the code which you are using

Comment: @AmritpalSingh i need to enable paste function but want to validate on paste and show an error message 'Please enter valid text'

Comment: On which event do you bind the validation ? Show a bit of your implementation otherwise we obsviously cannot help you.

Comment: Validate it onblur event event.

Comment: @rutwikreddy you should validate on submit rather if it suits your requirement

Comment: on which event you have called the validating function?? you should validate the text box on onchange() event. this should work.

Comment: The validation is on keydown() event

Comment: i want regexp to validate the entire string on paste instead of the single character

Comment: so whats the problem with it.
validate the whole text box string. you can do easily with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question is tagged with jquery, you can bind also to the paste event. In this case, use the method [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to attach the same handler for multiple events (whitespace-separated):

```
$('#someElement').bind('keydown paste', function() {
    // run some code when pasting or on keydown
});
```

Comment: i was wondering how to do it.. should i do .each() of every character on paste and validate it with regexp or is there any best way to do it?

Comment: You could have one method that uses regex to validate some string. And have two event handlers that calls this method: the handler for keydown event will pass the entered character, the handler for paste event will pass the entire pasted value. But it depends also on how you'd like to restrict: either you validate and say the string contains an invalid character, or you forbid some characters from being typed and then you would rather have a clean-up method that removes the unwanted characters.

Comment: Ok say i have a text box to enter first name where in user is only allowed to enter alphabets and nothing else, Even though user pastes the content my regex should be able to clean the non-alphabets entered.

Comment: Well now you know how to bind to the paste event so you can do it whatever way pleases you most...